# Wie würde ein Bauer eine inoffizielle Liebhaberin seines Lords bezeichnen?

Tags: single-word-request

Mittelalterliches Setting, ein verheirateter Lord bringt aus einem Feldzug ein nicht-adeliges Mädchen als Trophäe mit, seine Frau ist natürlich nicht begeistert. Wie würde ein nicht-adeliger Mann das Mädchen bezeichnen?

*Mätresse* und *Kurtisane* stehen für adelige Frauen, *Liebhaberin* klingt gefühlt zu modern (vielleicht täusche ich mich aber), *Geliebte* passt nicht zur Situation als Gefangene. Ist eine dieser Optionen doch passend, oder gibt es vielleicht eine andere, die ich übersehen habe?

Comment: VTC. Das hängt von vielem ab, in einem Fantasiescnenario hat man da freie Hand und was der eine als 'mittelalterlich' ansieht mag der andere als spät-römisch oder nach-mittelalterlich oder sogar modern bezeichnen. Feudalismus gibt's immer noch in der Welt. Außerdem hat es einen leicht frauenfeindlichen Beigeschmack ('Trophäe').

Comment: @a_donda: I'm not sure that's a valid reason; we should be able ask about the correct use of *Drache* or *Einhorn* here. I'm not sure why *Mädchen* wouldn't work though. I think a smart peasant would feign blindness in this situation, *Mädchen? Ich sah kein Mädchen.*

Comment: @RDBury Good point, but in this case, the peasant explains the situation to another person and needs to make clear what is happening. I only mentioned the fact that a peasant is talking, because he would use rather simple language; not because he is not in a position to judge.

Comment: Ein *Lord* würde im deutschen Sprachgebiet wohl eher anders heißen. Vielleicht passt *Konkubine*? Zumindest das Wort gibt es seit laut [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Konkubine) seit etwa 1400.

Comment: Konkubine klingt nach altem Rom oder Griechenland, also ein wenig zu alt, oder bin ich da auf dem falschen Dampfer? Im Original (Russisch) heißt es tatsächlich "Liebhaberin", ich hatte irgendwie das Gefühl, dass das ein zu modernes Wort für das Setting ist, aber vielleicht ist die Sorge unbegründet...

Comment: Byzantinisch (römisch) und mittelalterlich existieren ca. 1000 Jahr parallel. Konkubine hat zwar lateinische Wurzeln, ist aber wohl eher neuzeitlich im Sprachgebrauch. Schau, schnapp dir einen Begriff den du für richtig hältst, es handelt sich ja eh um eine Fantasiewelt mit Drachen etc. Da gibt's einfach keine objektiv gute Antwort.

Comment: Guter Tipp :) Das Ding ist, ich bin kein Muttersprachler und fühle mich gerade bei Wörtern, die mir nicht geläufig sind, weil sie in der Alltagssprache kaum auftauchen, sehr unsicher. Und möchte vermeiden, dass man als Leser über ein Wort stolpert und denkt "Hmm, das klingt ja schief, seltsam, dass das Wort in diesem Kontext auftaucht...". Bin da vielleicht ein wenig zu vorsichtig...

Comment: Ein wichtiger Aspekt ist meiner Meinung nach, wie der Bauer die neue Beziehung bewertet, beziehungsweise was er sich zu sagen traut. Wenn der Bauer die Beziehung missbilligt, würde ich durchaus über drastische bis obszöne Begriffe nachdenken, etwa "Seine Lordschaft hat sich eine kleine Hure mitgebracht". Wenn der Bauer die Beziehung nicht missbilligt (oder sich nicht den Zorn seines Herrn zuziehen will), würde ich in Richtung irgendeines Euphemismus' denken. "Seine Gefährtin", "sein Mündel", vielleicht sogar ein überzogener Eupemismus wie die "Näherinnen" in Pratchetts Scheibenwelt.

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck Es geht um eine Übersetzung, hätte ich wohl in der Fragestellung erwähnen sollen. "Hure" und "Gefährtin" sind zu weit weg vom Original "Liebhaberin" und passen nicht ins weitere Dialog. Die Frage ist nur, ob "Liebhaberin" zu modern für das Setting ist und ein anderes, aber sonst vom Sinn her ähnliches Wort, besser geeignet wäre.

Comment: Genau, der würde wohl in der Öffentlichkeit die Klappe halten, es sei denn seine Durchlaucht wäre von seinen Lieferungen abhängig. Und jetzt sind wir in World Building :-)

Comment: Wie würde der Adlige selbst sie bezeichnen? Gibt es einen Grund für die Annahme, dass ein Nicht-Adliger sie anders bezeichnen würde?

Comment: Das weiß ich auch nicht, aber grundsätzlich unterscheiden sich doch die Sprachen von Adeligen und von Bauern, die Adeligen drücken sich gewählter aus.

Comment: @Photon: Nein, das kann man grundsätzlich nicht so verallgeimernd sagen. Das feudale Völkchen konnte und kann auch ganz gut abgehen. Auch in modernen Zeiten sind einige der Nachfahren wegen ungebührlichen Benehmens geradezu berüchtigt.

Comment: "bringt aus einem Feldzug ein nicht-adeliges Mädchen als Trophäe mit" - heißt das, dass er sie gewaltsam entführt hat? Oder ist sie freiwillig mitgekommen? Nur im zweiten Fall wäre es angemessen, sie als Liebhaberin o.ä. zu bezeichnen.

Comment: Wie würd ein Marsianer in einer seinen auch für Fritz verständlichen, telepathischen Gebärde etwas bezeichnen das OP als Liebhaberin bezeichnen würde, wo aber keine Liebhaberin ist? Oder in anderen Worten: Antwort sucht Frage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Die Frage ist schwer zu beantworten, weil die Antwort in jedem Fall anachronistisch ist.

Wirklich gesagt hätte er etwas auf Mittelhochdeutsch, und was immer das war ("Kebse" ist in der Tat ein starker Kandidat, aber das wäre dann *kebese*, wie z.B. in [*Daz er sie zv kebese wil han*](http://www.mhdwb-online.de/konkordanz.php?lid=88011000&seite=1)), würde heute andere Konnotationen haben, falls man es denn überhaupt versteht.

In einem Fantasieszenario sollte man sich wohl an etwas orientieren, was vertraut klingt, grob in den Kontext und populäre Literatur darüber passt, und nicht offensichtlich andere Assozationen weckt. Da *jedwede* Fantasy-Literatur einen gewisse Affinität zur Sprache des 19.Jh. hat (denn damals wurden die Originaltexte gesammelt und erstmals übersetzt, auf denen die spätere Fantasy-Literatur aufgebaut hat), ist wohl am besten, historisierende Texte *dieser Zeit* auf ihre Wortwahl zu prüfen. "Mätresse" und "Kurtisane" scheiden meiner Meinung nach klar aus, die haben starke Assoziationen zum 18.Jh. "Liebhaberin" fühlt sich zu modern an, ich bin nicht sicher, ob es überhaupt schon "Liebhaber" gab. "Liebste" ginge vielleicht noch, auch wenn das klar euphemistisch ist. Mittelhochdeutsch gab es [Liebschaft](http://www.mhdwb-online.de/konkordanz.php?lid=102591000&seite=1) schon, das war wohl noch ein reines Abstraktum.

Ludwig Bechstein hat z.B. in einer ähnlich gelagerten [Sage](https://eden.one/bechstein-sagenbuch-der-graf-von-gleichen) ganz darauf verzichtet, eine Frau in dieser Rolle eindeutig zu bezeichnen, sondern beschreibt sie nach ihrem ethnischen Hintergrund ("sarazenische Jungfrau", "schöne Heidin", "Sarazenin", "Türkin"). Wenn man weiß, dass sie im Feldzug mitgebracht wurde, wäre so etwas wohl der natürlichste Impuls. Dafür sprechen übrigens aus unsere Nachnamen. Die sind vor Mitte des 16.Jh. (als sie verpflichtend wurden) entstanden und sehr häufig beziehen sie sich auf ethnische (Wendt, Sasse, Frank) oder geographische Herkunft (alle Personennamen auf -burg oder -dorf), also war Herkunft aus der Ferne ein wichtiges definitorisches Unterscheidungsmerkmal.

Comment: Bechsteins Sage ist in keiner Weise ähnlich gelagert. "Auf einem Ritt in die Wüste wurde der Graf gefangen genommen und in schwerer Dienstbarkeit als ein Sklave gehalten. Endlich, da er als ein Gärtner arbeitete, nahm die schöne Tochter des Sultans seiner wahr und gewann ihn lieb, auch entdeckte seiner mitgefangenen Diener einer ihr seinen Stand. Da bot sie ihm Befreiung, sich selbst und alle ihre Schätze an, wenn er sie zum ehelichen Weibe nehmen und mit ihr entfliehen wolle." Die *schöne Heidin* war also kein Opfer, das unfreiwillig als Gefangene in die Heimat des Grafen kam.

Comment: Auch wenn die Antwort fünf upvotes erhielt und vom OP akzeptiert wurde - ich halte sie für völlig verfehlt.

Comment: Sagen wir mal, die Antwort ist im Sinne einer Hilfestellung zum Schreiben formuliert, denn das scheint der Kontext der Frage zu sein. Interessiert man sich für die Lexikographie des Mittelhochdeutschen, wäre die Antwort anders, aber ich bezweifle stark, dass ein Fragesteller, der in dem Zusammenhang von einem Adligen als "Lord" spricht, das wirklich im Sinn hatte.

Answer (score 4):

Ich schlage die "[Kebse](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kebse)", bzw. das "Kebsweib" vor.

[dwds.de](https://www.dwds.de/wb/etymwb/Kebse) schreibt zur Etymologie unter anderem:

> Kebse f. ‘nicht rechtmäßig angetraute Frau, Nebenfrau’. Die im Westgerm. bezeugten femininen Bildungen ahd. kebis (9. Jh.), kebisa (11. Jh.), mhd. kebes(e), kebse (auch ‘nicht rechtsgültige Ehe, Konkubinat’), asächs. keƀis, mnd. kēves, mnl. kevese (auch ‘Küchenmagd’ und ‘Ehebruch’), kevisse, kefse, aengl. cifes, neben denen ein Maskulinum anord. kefsir ‘Sklave’ (eigentlich wohl ‘verheirateter Unfreier, dessen Ehe nicht als rechtmäßig gilt’) steht, sind bisher nicht sicher erklärt;

Nachtrag: Wie in den Kommentaren richtig festgestellt wurde, wird Kebse/Kebsweib heutzutage selten verwendet. Es wurde aber auch noch nicht aus dem [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Kebse) gestrichen. Ich kann nur von mir selber berichten, dass ich weder Germanist noch Mediävalist bin, und die Begriffe trotzdem irgendwo aufgeschnappt habe.

Letzlich liegt es in der Hand des Autors/Übersetzters zwischen Authentizität und Verständlichkeit abzuwiegen:
Einzelne seltene Worte kann sich das Zielpuplikum vielleicht aus dem Kontext erschließen. Wenn man das dem Publikum nicht zutraut oder zumuten möchte, wählt man bekanntere Wörter, läuft aber unter Umständen Gefahr, das altertümliche Flair einzubüßen.

Comment: Danke für den Tipp, das Wort kannte ich gar nicht!

Comment: Vermutlich würde "Kebse" kaum ein heutiger Leser verstehen.

Comment: Ah, dann liegt das also nicht nur daran, dass ich kein Muttersprachler, dass mir das Wort unbekannt ist. Dann bleibe ich vielleicht tatsächlich bei "Liebhaberin"...

Comment: "Wie es tatsächlich gesagt worden wäre" und "was Leser heute verstehen würden" haben oft wenig miteinander zu tun. Solange man nicht für ein Publikum von Mediävalisten schreibt, dürfte z.B. "Mätresse" geeigneter sein, obwohl es historisch gesehen zu einer ganz anderen Epoche gehört.

Comment: Wenn der Bauer sagt, "die neue Kebse vom Grafen hab ich wieder gesehen" dürfte aus dem Kontext Recht schnell klar sein, was gemeint ist

Comment: In manchen Teilen Österreichs wird das Wort durchaus noch im Alltag verwendet. Zumindest in der Obersteiermark hört man"Kebsn" auch noch hin und wieder bei Jugendlichen. Ob es auch anderswo noch verwendet wird, weiß ich nicht.

Answer (score 2):

Mittelalterliches Denken und mittelalterliche Sprachgepflogenheiten sind uns fremd geworden. Eine aktuelle Textübersetzung sollte nicht den Ehrgeiz haben, altes Wortgut "auszugraben", sondern sollte leicht verständlich sein.

Aus der Frage geht nicht eindeutig hervor, was das "Mitbringen eines nicht-adeligen Mädchen als Trophäe aus einem Feldzug" bedeutet. Hat der Lord sie gegen ihren Willen gezwungen, mit ihm zu kommen? Handelte es sich also um Menschenraub (sozusagen um eine "Kriegsbeute", man verzeihe das Wort in diesem Kontext)? Oder wurde sie ihm "verkauft"?

Jedenfalls deutet der Satz "Geliebte passt nicht zur Situation als Gefangene" darauf hin, dass sie nicht freiwillig (in der Hoffnung auf ein besseres Leben an der Seite des Lords) mitgekommen ist.

Unter diesen Umständen ist es m.E. völlig verfehlt, sie als Dirne oder Hure zu bezeichnen. Im Gegenteil ist sie eine Art Sklavin und auch der einfache Bauer würde ihr vermutlich nicht vorwerfen, sie würde sich prostituieren.

Mein Vorschlag: **Gespielin.**

Das Wort hat eine gewisse Bandbreite an Bedeutungen (Geliebte, Liebhaberin, Mätresse, Verhältnis, ...) und lässt m.E. offen, wie freiwillig oder unfreiwillig ihre Beziehung zum Lord entstand.

Eine Alternative für die heutige Leserschaft könnte auch **[Sexsklavin](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Sexsklavin)** sein. Das Wort hätte zwar kein mittelalterlicher Bauer gekannt bzw. verwendet und hat außerdem deutliche Konnotationen zur Porno-Industrie, aber der traurige Kern ist der sexuelle Missbrauch von Frauen und Mädchen. Vgl. z.B. [hier](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wchai7KdiE4).

Eine weitere Variante ist **Bettsklavin**. Dieses Wort hat es sogar in den [SPIEGEL](https://www.spiegel.de/geschichte/deutscher-kolonialismus-in-afrika-wo-steckt-der-kopf-des-mangi-meli-a-1e5ab093-222a-4453-93d3-597e8aea417c) gebracht:

> Der sadistische Pfarrerssohn [Carl Peters] war ab 1891 Reichskommissar für das Kilimandscharo-Gebiet. Er ließ alle aufknüpfen, die ihm in die Quere kamen: Aufständische, Nebenbuhler, sogar seine Bettsklavin.

Hier noch einige weitere Referenzen:

[1.](https://sabine.knienieder.com/homer-ilias-hintergrund/)

> Eine dieser Gefangenen war die Trojanerin Chryseis, die zur Bettsklavin Agamemnons wurde.

[2.](https://www.jpc.de/jpcng/books/detail/-/art/helga-glaesener-das-erbe-der-paepstin/hnum/9808135)

> Gisla wird bei einem Überfall von Normannen geschändet, entführt und lebt ab da als Sklavin in einem dänischen Dorf. Ihr zukünftiger Herr wählt sie als Bettsklavin und Gisla wird so Mutter zweier Töchter.

Comment: Ich bezweifle mal, dass ein mittelalterlicher Bauer wußte, was *eine Gespielin* ist.

Comment: @tofro Völlig richtig (wie auch das Wort "Sexsklavin"), aber es soll ja eine Übersetzung erstellt werren, die der heutigen Leserschaft verständlich ist. Vgl. den ersten Absatz meiner Antwort.

Answer (score 1):

Mittelalter ist ein langer Zeitraum, ich würde das grob als von 300-1400 unserer Zeitrechnung verstehen. Adelige gab es Deutschland deutlich länger, bis 1918, wenn ich recht informiert bin.

Das Problem mit Bezeichnungen allgemein, die um 800 oder 1100 gebräuchlich waren, ist, dass sie heute nur mit Glück noch verstanden werden.

Hier würde ich beispielsweise

## Dirne

vorschlagen, das heute noch sporadisch für Prostituierte benutzt wird, aber früher allgemein gebräuchlich war für Mädchen, siehe die Kinderliedzeile "Spannenlanger Hansel, nudeldicke Dirn". Das mag aber auch etwas über die soziale Wirklichkeit von vor 150-200 Jahren etwas aussagen. Solche Sprachfeinheiten sind aber den meisten Zeitgenossen, die das nicht studieren, nicht bewusst, d.h. Dirne könnte aus den falschen Gründen richtig verstanden werden.

Wie weit Dirne zurückreicht, ob das im Mittelalter schon im Gebrauch war, weiß ich aber nicht.

Es stellt sich die Frage, an welches Publikum der Text sich richten soll, wie viel Wissen man da vorraussetzt, ob man eine Fußnote im Text setzen kann oder erwarten, dass ein Leser Wörter, die er nicht kennt, nachschlägt.

Nachschlagen kann man bspw. im [Göthe Wörterbuch](https://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/GWB/Dirne), im [Grimmschen](https://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemid=D02672) oder im [Rheinischen Wörterbuch](https://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/RhWB/Dirne) und dort findet man auch, dass die Bezeichnungen regional sehr unterschiedlich sind.

Eine historisch korrekte Bezeichnung müsste also sowohl die Zeit als auch den Ort sehr viel genauer einkreisen, aber da sich das Mittelalter auch dadurch auszeichnet, dass da noch wenig geschrieben wurde, dürfte die Quellenlage sehr löchrig sein.

Comment: 300 im Jahre des Erren, Mitte lalter? Homer ist dann frühe Neuzeit und Vorgeschichte gibts quas i nicht weil per definitione nicht dokumen ti iert

Comment: @vectory Als "Mittelalter" wird meist die Zeit zwischen dem 6. und 15. Jahrhundert bezeichnet, vgl. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittelalter. Egal, der Vorschlag "Dirne" ist doch wohl Ernst zu nehmen.

Answer (score 0):

Wahrscheinlich hätte der mittelalterliche Bauer nicht lange in seinem (nicht vorhandenen) Duden nach einem Wort gesucht, sondern hätte rustikal das erste, was ihm eingefallen wäre, benutzt.

> Die Hure vom Grafen

Man muss sich klarmachen, dass in einem stark religiösen und eher naiven mittelalterlichen Setting die einzige vorstellbare außereheliche Verbindung zwischen einem Mann und einer Frau die zwischen Hure und Freier war.

Comment: Sicher hätte ein mittelalterlicher Bauer soviel Urteilskraft gehabt, um die Rolle einer Gefangenen (die als "Kriegstrophäe" mitgebracht wude) von der Rolle einer Hure zu unterscheiden.

Answer (score -1):

Wie schon Arsak schrieb, wären Kebse oder noch besser Kebsweib, bzw. Kebsfrau gute Kandidaten. Vor allem bei zweitem könnte Leser:innen, die das Wort nicht kennen, je nach Schreibstil, den Zusammenhang erahnen. Die jetzige Unbekanntheit des Worts ist allerdings auch sein größter Nachteil.

Es kommt natürlich vor allem darauf an, was der Bauer ausdrücken will. Verachtung? Bewunderung? Neutralität? All dies wird aus der Frage nicht ersichtlich. Nur, dass die Frau des Fürsten nicht begeistert ist davon. Sie würde diese deutlich negativer bezeichnen. Es sei denn natürlich es ist ein Setting in dem es "normal" für den Fürsten ist weitere Frauen zu haben.

Aber zurück zum Bauern. Durchaus damals gebräuchliche neutrale Begriffe, die auch für Leser:innen nachvollziehbar sind wären

> Beifrau

bzw.

> Beischläferin

Sollte es ins positive gehen wäre

> Liebchen

möglich.

Ins negative die

> Metze

Wobei das dann wieder dasselbe Problem, wie die Kebse hat

Answer (score -3):

By her name most likely, if available, must be the prefered form of address, as people started to confuse ''Regina'' for a name. This can be used to avoid any form of judgement unless so intended, in which case it is entirely subjective, probably dictated by some in a sense that would remain open to interpretation.

PS: ***Hure*** is a very likely option, as it literally translated "lover", I suppose (akin to French *cher* "dear"), but the etymology of such a word has to be taken with a grain of salt and I advise (heavily, no less) against actually using it. Point in case though, it is said that pros prefer "Hure" over "Nutte" (e.g. in a certain Vereinsname). Accquired Latinism are of course a noble choice, and French a cheeper alternative that's a little more familiar today, e.g. 'Madame' vs. 'Mademoisel', 'Mrs' vs 'Ms', 'Frau' vs. 'Freundin' (where the first should represent like *dame* "domina" *Freya* "Venus", and the other as *love*, cp. *Freier*, *freien*, *girlfriend*, 'belong to the clan'). See also *hoary*, *hehr*, *Herr* (implying *grey hair*, it is said) and relatedly *shadow* (in the dark, unknown).